# is UITabBarItem already selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar

I am selecting a tabbaritem and loading a view  up from the bottom of my screen, I would like to then reselect the same tabbar item to close this view.. however I am not sure how to approach this.

I have looked in the tabbar api and I cannot see anything that is of help and am wondering if anyone here has a good idea to achieve my desired outcome.

Comment: this view that you are loading is like a pop-up over the intended tab bar view?

Comment: hrmm.. I should say I have created a whole viewcontroller that holds my tabbar which I then add as a subview to my mainview. then when I select a tabitem I load a new subview over my mainview by behind my tabbarview..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused by this still. Why are you not just using a TabBarController that has your ViewControllers for each page?

Comment: Yea well its a fairly complex view.. it has a navigaitoncontroller in which you can swipe between views, each view inside the navigation controller has a tabbar (which i have made into one tab bar thats icons will change) and views that pop up from the navigation bar when the tabbaritems are selected.

Comment: FYI, you are not allowed to put a tab bar inside of a navigation controller.  Your app will not be approved by Apple like this.

Comment: right, I dont think i explained myself right. The tabbar is in a viewcontroller, this viewcontroller (which has the tabbar in it) is loaded as a subview of the navigation controller.. is that still bad?

Comment: A tab bar controller cannot be part of a view controller, it has to encapsulate a (or multiple) view controller(s). Those view controllers can have navigation controllers, but not the other way around. A tab bar controller is always at the top of the hierarchy.

Comment: can you place a tabbar in its own viewcontroller?